# How to show "value"[column] and "sum of all such values"[row wise] for a group of EmpId in the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to show "value"[column] and "sum of all such values"[row wise] for a group of EmpId in the same row.

```
SELECT ID, SUM(VALUE1), SUM(VALUE2) 
GROUP BY EmpID
```

The above query will return the sum, but I also want to show values of Value1 and Value2 in the same row.

E.g.

I have following input table:

```
EmpID  VALUE1  VALUE2
==================
1       1       5         
1       2       6         
2       3       7         
2       4       8
```

I want following output table (grouped by EmpID) -> Both Value1, Value2 and their sum in same row

```
EmpID  Value1  VALUE2  total_Value1   total_Value2
===============================================
1       1       5         3               11
1       2       6         3               11
2       3       7         7               15     
2       4       8         7               15
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `SUM() OVER(PARTITION BY)` window function, you can get your expected result:

```
SELECT EmpID, VALUE1, VALUE2,
       SUM(VALUE1) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID) AS total_Value1,   
       SUM(VALUE2) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID) AS total_Value2
FROM TableName
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fa6bfada9dfb39ce0fb960d6e0ffb743)

Comment: @Pranay Is the answer helpful? Also if it solved your problem, can you please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/312043)

Answer (score 2):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(SUM(VALUE1)) OVER (PARTITION BY id),
       SUM(SUM(VALUE2)) OVER (PARTITION BY id)
FROM T
GROUP BY EmpID;
```

However, I don't think aggregation is needed:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(VALUE1) OVER (PARTITION BY id),
       SUM(VALUE2) OVER (PARTITION BY id)
FROM T;
```

Comment: . . .  Window function with aggregation would this really work ?

Comment: @YogeshSharma . . . Yes, with the right syntax, but I don't think the aggregation is needed.